# Conditionally Project Matching Array Item

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection named `questions` with documents like this:

```
{
    "formats": [
        {
            "language_id": 1,
            "text": "question text1"
        },
        {
            "language_id": 2,
            "text": "question text 2"
        }
    ],
    "qid": "HQSRFA3T"
}
```

I want to write a query such that if a specific `language_id` is not present, then `language_id` with 1 should be returned by default.

I've tried two queries so far:

```
db.questions.aggregate([
  { 
    $match: {
      'qid': 'HQSRFA3T'
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      formats: {
        $ifNull: [
          { $filter: { input: '$formats', as: 'format', cond: {$eq: ['$$format.language_id', 3]}} },
          { $filter: { input: '$formats', as: 'format', cond: {$eq: ['$$format.language_id', 1]}} }
        ]
      },
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

This query results in something like this:

`{ "formats" : [ ] }`

Then there's another query which is something like this:

```
db.questions.aggregate([ { $match: {'qid': 'HQSRFA3T'}}, { $project: {
  formats: {
    $filter: {
      input: '$formats',
      as: 'format',
      cond: {
        $or: [
          { $eq: ['$$format.language_id', 1] },
          { $eq: ['$$format.language_id', 3] }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  _id: 0
}}])
```

This query returns two elements in case both `language_id`'s are present in the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a "few" ways:

Ideally you have [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) from MongoDB 3.4 then you can use that in combination with [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/):

```
db.questions.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "qid": "HQSRFA3T" } },
  { "$project": {
    "formats": {
      "$cond": {
        "if": { "$in": [ 3, "$formats.language_id"] },
        "then": { 
          "$arrayElemAt": [
            "$formats",
            { "$indexOfArray": [ "$formats.language_id", 3 ] }
          ]
        },
        "else": {
          "$arrayElemAt": [
            "$formats",
            { "$indexOfArray": [ "$formats.language_id", 1 ] }
          ]
        }
      }
    }}
  }
])
```

And if all you really want is the matching `"text"`, then a slight alteration:

```
db.questions.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "qid": "HQSRFA3T" } },
  { "$project": {
    "text": {
      "$cond": {
        "if": { "$in": [ 3, "$formats.language_id"] },
        "then": { 
          "$arrayElemAt": [
            "$formats.text",
            { "$indexOfArray": [ "$formats.language_id", 3 ] }
          ]
        },
        "else": {
          "$arrayElemAt": [
            "$formats.text",
            { "$indexOfArray": [ "$formats.language_id", 1 ] }
          ]
        }
      }
    }}
  }
])
```

That works because if the [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) returns `-1` indicating "not found" then the the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) will branch accordingly:

Alternately, use [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) with [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/):

```
db.questions.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "qid": "HQSRFA3T" } },
  { "$project": {
    "formats": {
      "$cond": {
        "if": { "$gt": [
          { "$size": { 
            "$filter": { 
              "input": "$formats",
               "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$this.language_id", 3 ] }
            }
          }},
          0
        ]},
        "then": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$formats",
            "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$this.language_id", 3 ] }
          }
        },
        "else": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$formats",
            "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$this.language_id", 1 ] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

You can even vary on the last form with [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to just return the "single" matching array element at position `0` if you at least have MongoDB 3.2.

```
db.questions.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "qid": "HQSRFA3T" } },
  { "$project": {
    "formats": {
      "$cond": {
        "if": { "$gt": [
          { "$size": { 
            "$filter": { 
              "input": "$formats",
               "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$this.language_id", 3 ] }
            }
          }},
          0
        ]},
        "then": {
          "$arrayElemAt": [
            { "$filter": {
              "input": "$formats",
              "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$this.language_id", 3 ] }
            }},
            0
          ]
        },
        "else": {
          "$arrayElemAt": [
            { "$filter": {
              "input": "$formats",
              "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$this.language_id", 1 ] }
            }},
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Other alternatives on the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) for the `if` condition are using [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/), to match the comparison on the array elements:

```
"if": { "$in": [ 3, "$formats.language_id" ] }
```

But since that requires MongoDB 3.4, then you may as well use the [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) operator instead.

There is very little point in trying to "force" multiple matches into [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and then ultimately looking to discard one of them, but you "can" do it with [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/):

```
db.questions.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "qid": "HQSRFA3T" } },
  { "$project": {
    "formats": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          "formats": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$formats",
              "cond": {
                "$or": [
                  { "$eq": [ "$$this.language_id", 1 ] },
                  { "$eq": [ "$$this.language_id", 3 ] }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "in": {
           "$cond": {
             "if": {
               "$gt": [
                 { "$size": {
                   "$filter": {
                     "input": "$$formats",
                     "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$this.language_id", 3 ] }
                   }
                 }},
                 0
               ]
             },
             "then": {
               "$filter": {
                 "input": "$$formats",
                 "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$this.language_id", 3 ] }
               }
             },
             "else": {
               "$filter": {
                 "input": "$$formats",
                 "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$this.language_id", 1 ] }
               }
             }
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

So it's there, but it's just extra work with little gain since at best the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/) condition matches the "default" case and you still needed to "filter away" for only the "preferred" match anyway.

Comment: The first query would return wrong result as `$indexOfArray` returns -1 and `$arrayElemAt` gives the last element in the array according to the docs.

Comment: @RahulSharma Argh! Your right of course `$ifNull` is probably not the best thing then.

Comment: I wanted to write a query which fallbacks to picking up the `language_id` 1 which is correctly achieved using the third query. I was just pointing out that in case $indexOfArray returns -1, $arrayElemAt won't return null. Thanks anyways for your help for the third query.

Comment: @RahulSharma I modified the first one anyway. `$ifNull` won't work because there is nothing that returns `null`, Therefore `$cond` works in all cases.